# SQL Server 2005 Getting the last record of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm new with SQL Server. I'm trying to convert my Access Database into SQL Server.
Here is my problem I got a Table here.

```
CarID    CustomerName     Date Replied           StatusID    Offer
  1          Karl           05-01-2013               1        $1000
  1          Karl           05-02-2013               1        $1000
  1          Kathy           05-03-2013              1        $1500
  1          Karl           05-04-2013               2        $1000
  2          Karl           05-04-2013               1        $2000
```

I want to display my data as

```
 CarID    CustomerName     Date Replied           StatusID    Offer
   1          Kathy          05-03-2013               1       $1500
   1          Karl           05-04-2013               2       $1000
   2          Karl           05-04-2013               1       $2000
```

In MS Access

`I used SELECT CarID, Last(CustomerName) as CustomerName, Max(Date) as Date Replied, Last(StatusID) as StatusID, Last(Offer) as Offer from viewCarOffers GROUP BY CarID`

Problem with SQL Server. It doesn't have last function. I don't have any idea on how to get this same result using SQL Server.

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a view for this record. it's actually a nested / relational table. (tblCars, tblMake, tblCarOffers, tblModel, etc...)

Comment: It appears that the Last() function returns the last record from the table (after a quick google search this is what I found, I'm ot familiar with ms access myself). Unless you know the order they were inserted I'm not sure you can replicate this. If you have an insert timestamp or an identity to know the insert order you could use a subquery like `(select top 1 vco.customername from viewCarOffers _vco where vco.carId = viewCarOffers.customerName order by {identity or timestamp} desc)` in the query in place of `Last(CustomerName)`. Repeat for you other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT o.CarID,
       o.CustomerName,
       o.Date 'Date Replied',
       o.StatusID,
       o.Offer
  FROM
(
SELECT CarID, CustomerName, MAX(Date) Date
  FROM viewCarOffers 
GROUP BY CarID, CustomerName
) q JOIN  viewCarOffers o
    ON o.CarID = q.CarID 
   AND o.CustomerName = q.CustomerName 
   AND q.Date = o.Date
 ORDER BY CarID, CustomerName
```

Output:

```
| CARID | CUSTOMERNAME |               DATE REPLIED | STATUSID | OFFER |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 |         Karl | May, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        2 | $1000 |
|     1 |        Kathy | May, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        1 | $1500 |
|     2 |         Karl | May, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        1 | $2000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4848/8)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  CarId,
  CustomerName,
  DATE,
  StatusId,
  Offer
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY carid, CustomerName ORDER BY DATE DESC) ROW, *
  FROM viewCarOffers
) vco
WHERE ROW = 1
ORDER BY CarId, offer DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you can do a self join to a select of the largest date.

```
SELECT co.CarID, 
    Last.CustomerName AS CustomerName, 
    Last.Date AS [DATE Replied], 
    Last.StatusID AS StatusID, 
    Last.Offer AS Offer 
FROM viewCarOffers co
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY DATE DESC) ROW,
            CarId,
            CustomerName,
            DATE,
            StatusId,
            Offer
        FROM viewCarOffers co2
    ) LAST ON co.carid = last.carid AND last.row = 1
GROUP BY co.CarId, Last.CustomerName, Last.Date, Last.StatusId, Last.Offer
```

I don't quite get the results you are asking for though, shouldn't your select only return a single a row per car?